# Fullcalendar substring date returns Uncaught TypeError: info.event.end.substring is not a function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, substring, timepicker

I have a fullcalendar in which i'm using a jquery timepicker.
On event click i need to take the start properties (example: "Wed May 04 2022 11:30:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)") but using the substring to only have HH:MM.
I tried doing: "var x= info.event.end.substring(16, 21);" but when i click an event this error occure: "Uncaught TypeError: info.event.end.substring is not a function"
How can i fix this?

Comment: You'll need to include more context (in terms of code and full errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`end` is a `Date` object, and `substring` only works on `String` objects. Add `.toString()` and you'll be able to progress.

```
var x= info.event.end.toString().substring(16, 21);
```

Comment: can you paste in your `eventClick:` routine @FilippoCanino? it should only be saying that if `end` is null. Is it an `allDay` event?